# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'name' when using repair job in Azure Databricks

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I want to run a repair job (MSCK REPAIR TABLE) in Azure Databricks, excludig 4 tables. What am I doing wrong?

```
database = "demo"
tables = spark.catalog.listTables(database)

tables = spark.sql("show tables in demo")

tables = tables.filter((tables.tableName  != "example1") & (tables.tableName  != "example2") & (tables.tableName  != "example3") & (tables.tableName  != "example4")) 

for i in tables.collect():
print(i)

for table in tables:
   spark.sql(f"MSCK REPAIR TABLE {database}.{table.name}")`
```

I´ll get following error message:

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent
> call last)
>
> `<command-2033459303290955> in <module>`
>
> ```
> 1 for i in tables:
> ```
>
> ----> 2    spark.sql(f"MSCK REPAIR TABLE {database}.{table.name}")
>
> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'name'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two errors:

1. You don't collect data to the driver node - in this case you just iterate over the list of columns in the `tables` dataframe
2. You use the wrong name for the column - it's not the `name`, but `tableName`.

This should work:

```py
database = "demo"
tables = spark.sql(f"show tables in {database}")

tables = tables.filter((tables.tableName  != "example1") & (tables.tableName  != "example2") & (tables.tableName  != "example3") & (tables.tableName  != "example4")) 

for table in tables.collect():
   spark.sql(f"MSCK REPAIR TABLE {database}.{table.tableName}")`
```

P.S. Plus you have duplicate code